# cloudfoundry_controller cannot start

Tags: cloud-foundry

I want to ask something about cloudfoundry .. 
I installed cloudfoundry on my local sytem using this tutorial .[how to install cloudfoundry server paas](http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2011/08/howto-install-cloudfoundry-server-paas.html) from ppa repository on ubuntu 12.04 .

Then i run it with syntax : `$ sudo /etc/init.d/cloudfoundry-server start`
and the result is :

```
router              :    RUNNING

cloud_controller    :    RUNNING

dea                 :    RUNNING

health_manager      :    RUNNING
```

But when i restart ,it said that cloud_controller STOPED

The I restart it manually from syntax : `$ /opt/cloudfoundry-server/vcap/bin/cloud-controller restart`

and the result is :

> Staging environment validation failed: sinatra runtime ruby18 version
>   was 1.9.3p0, expected to match 1.8.7

Can anybody help me ? please ??

Answer (score 1):

we recommend you follow the instructions in the readme at https://github.com/cloudfoundry/vcap/ and install on Ubuntu 10.04, although installing from source will take longer it will ensure you get the most recent version available.

Comment: That a good way sir , but my ubuntu is 32 bit system , so i use that link to install cloudfoundry-server .. 

any idea??

Comment: currently CF works best on an Ubuntu 10.04 installation, installed from source as Dan points out. The Ubuntu packages may not be particularly recent.

Comment: yes sir , i have tried it , i edited some line on vcap_dev_setup to use without proxy , 
but when it run and show : 
"[2012-08-01T07:44:03+07:00] INFO: Run List is .."
the proccess run too long .. and the final result was Error ?? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The url is for Ubuntu 11. Check [Andy's blog](http://andypiper.co.uk/2012/04/26/ubuntu-12-04-and-cloud-foundry/) regarding Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: I have checked on link u gave to me sir .. 

that's describe how to manage our apps on cloudfoundry cloud .. 

nice one sir .. 

but i wanna make the cloud PAAS with cloudfoundry server so i can do "vmc push" to my localhost ... 

hahah .. any idea??

Comment: if you just want to do this against localhost, have you considered using Micro Cloud Foundry running in a VM?

Comment: Im sorry to answer u too late sir .. 
yes , that's right , i tried it a few days later , but it didnt support for 32 bit system .. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

That error comes from inconsistent information between you cloud_controller and the staging manifests.
Look for a sinatra.yml file (the location depends on your setup, but you'll find it in your cloud_controller.yml).